# Using IRepository pattern for multiple domain objects and multiple storage mechanisms

Tags: c#, repository-pattern

This is a VERY simplified example to demonstrate a question.  While I am only showing two domain objects here, imagine there are many more with various parameters.

Let's say I have the following domain objects:

```
public class Object1
{
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Object2
{
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
    public int ItemValue { get; set; }
}
```

A typical implementation of the Repository pattern would have an Object1Repository and an Object2Repository where each implements some IRepository interface that may include methods like AddObject, DeleteObject, GetObjectByIdentifier, etc...  The repository would then know how to interact with a database to perform the suggested methods.

That is all well and good and I have used the Repository pattern in exactly this way many times.  Now I have a problem where I have multiple different storage mechanisms; Oracle, SQLServer, text file, and XML file.  What is the best design approach to support this idea?  A repository of repositories?  Basically what I am trying to achieve is to have multiple different objects be able to be stored to multiple different storage mediums and I am trying to apply the Repository pattern to this idea.

I am writing C# code, but I can read most other languages as well so a suggested approach doesn't necessarily have to be C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to [How would I design a repository to handle multiple data access strategies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079378/how-would-i-design-a-repository-to-handle-multiple-data-access-strategies) , I think this is what you want.

Basically assume you already have one IRepository interface having methods of CRUD and other generic methods refer by all your other  repository, then you have multi implementations to IRepository interface.

After that use any IOC container (I use Windsor Castle) to resolve which implement's component should take part for this interface doing application setup.

Comment: +1.  Also, you can use a plain old AbstractFactory to switch implementations if you don't want to use an IoC container.

Comment: Perfect.  I tried to search SO before posting this question and I didn't seem to find that linked question.  Thanks for taking the time.